# How can I best maintain integrity between two columns in a table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, referential-integrity, data-integrity

Hypothetically, I have an `ENUM` column named `Category`, and an `ENUM` column named `Subcategory`. I will sometimes want to `SELECT` on `Category` alone, which is why they are split out.

```
CREATE TABLE `Bonza` (
   `EventId`     INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Category`    ENUM("a", "b", "c") NOT NULL,
   `Subcategory` ENUM("x", "y", "z") NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(`EventId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

But not all subcategories are valid for all categories (say, `"z"` is only valid with `"a"` and `"b"`), and it irks me that this constraint isn't baked into the design of the table. If MySQL had some sort of "pair" type (where a column of that type were indexable on a leading subsequence of the value) then this wouldn't be such an issue.

I'm stuck with writing long conditionals in a trigger if I want to maintain integrity between category and subcategory. Or am I better off just leaving it? What would you do?

I suppose the most relationally-oriented approach would be storing an `EventCategoryId` instead, and mapping it to a table containing all valid event type pairs, and joining on that table every time I want to look up the meaning of an event category.

```
CREATE TABLE `Bonza` (
   `EventId`         INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `EventCategoryId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(`EventId`),
   FOREIGN KEY `EventCategoryId` REFEFRENCES(`EventCategories`.`EventCategoryId`)
     ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `EventCategories` (
   `EventCategoryId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `Category`    ENUM("a", "b", "c") NOT NULL,
   `Subcategory` ENUM("x", "y", "z") NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(`EventCategoryId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- Now populate this table with valid category/subcategory pairs at installation
```

Can I do anything simpler? This lookup will potentially cost me complexity and performance in calling code, for `INSERT`s into `Bonza`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your categories and subcategories don't change that often, and assuming that you're willing to live with a big update when they do, you can do the following:

Use an `EventCategories` table to control the hierarchical constraint between categories and subcategories.  The primary key for that table should be a **compound key** containing both `Category` and `Subcategory`.  Reference this table in your `Bonza` table.  The foreign key in `Bonza` happens to contain both of the columns that you want to filter by, so you don't need to join to get what you're after.  It will also be impossible to assign an invalid combination.

```
CREATE TABLE `Bonza` (
   `EventId`         UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `Category`        CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   `Subcategory`     CHAR(1) NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(`EventId`),
   FOREIGN KEY `Category`, `Subcategory` 
   REFEFRENCES(`EventCategories`.`Category`, `EventCategories`.`Subcategory`)
     ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `EventCategories` (
   `EventCategoryId` UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL,
   `Category`    CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
   `Subcategory` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY(`Category`, `Subcategory`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Ah, that's an excellent idea. Don't need `EventCategories.EventCategoryId` then...? I'd still want to stick with the `ENUM` I think, because I don't like freetext for finite sets and the values won't actually be single characters.

Answer (score 1):

*My thought is: "best" is almost always opinion-based, but still there are some common things that may be said*

## Using relational structure

Once you have an issue that not all pairs are valid - you have an issue - that **you must store** this information. Therefore, you need either to store *which pairs are invalid* or to store *which pairs are valid*. Your sample with additional table *is completely valid* in terms of relational DBMS. In fact, if we'll face such issue, it is near the only way to resolve it on database-design level. With it:

- You're storing *valid* pairs. That's as I've said: you have to store this information somewhere and here we are - creating new table
- You're maintaining referential integrity via `FOREIGN KEY`. So your data will always be correct and point to valid pair

What bad things may happen and how could this impact the performance?

- To reconstruct full row, you'll need to use simple `JOIN`:

  ```
  SELECT 
    Bonza.id, 
    EventCategories.Subcategory,
    EventCategories.Category
  FROM
    Bonza
      LEFT JOIN EventCategories
      ON Bonza.EventCategoryId=EventCategory.id
  ```
- Performance of this `JOIN` will be good: you'll do it be FK - thus, by definition, you'll get only `INDEX SCAN`. It is about index quality (i.e. it's cardinality) - but in general it will be fast.
- How complex is one `JOIN`? It's simple operation - but it may add some overhead to complex queries. However, in my opinion: it's ok. There's *nothing complex* in it.
- You are able to change pairs with a simple changing of `EventCategories` data. That is: you can easily remove restrictions on prohibited pairs and this will affect *nothing*. I see this as a great benefit of this structure. However, adding new restriction isn't so simple - because, yes, it requires `DELETE` operation. You've chosen `ON DELETE RESTRICT` action for your FK - and that means you'll have to handle all conflicting records before adding new restriction. This depends, of course, from your application's logic - but think of it another way: if you'll add new restriction, shouldn't then all conflicting records be removed (because logic is saying: *yes, they should*)? If so, then change your FK to `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

So: having additional table is *simple*, *flexible* and actually *easy* way to resolve your issue.

## Storing in one table

You've mentioned, that you can use trigger for your issue. And that is actually applicable, so I'll show - that this has it's weakness (well, together with some benefits). Let's say, we'll create the trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER catCheck BEFORE INSERT ON Bonza
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.Subcategory = "z" && NEW.Category = "c" THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Invalid category pair';
        END IF;
    END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Obviously, we still *have* to store information about how to validate our pairs, but in this case we store *invalid* combinations. Once we'll get invalid data, we'll catch this inside trigger and abort our insert, returning proper user-defined errno (`45000`) together with some explanation text. Now, what about complexity and performance?

- This way allows you to store your data as it is, in *one* table. This is a benefit: you'll get rid of `JOIN` - integrity is maintained by another tool. You may forget about storing pairs and handling them, hiding this logic in the trigger
- So, you'll win on `SELECT` statements: your data *always* contain valid pairs. And no `JOIN` would be needed
- But, yes, you'll *loose* on `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements: they will invoke trigger and within it - some checking condition. It may be complex (many `IF` parts) and MySQL will check them one by one. Making one single condition wouldn't help lot - because still, in worst case, MySQL will check it till it's end.
- Scalability of this method *is poor*. Every time you'll need to add/remove pair restriction - you'll have to redefine trigger. Even worse, unlike `JOIN` case, you'll not able to do any cascade actions. Instead you'll have to do manual handling.

## What to chose?

For common case, if you don't know for certain - what will be your application conditions, I recommend you to use `JOIN` option. It's simple, readable, scalable. It fits relational DB principles.

For some special cases, you may want to chose second option. Those conditions would be:

- Allowed pairs will never be changed (or will be changed very rare)
- `SELECT` statements will be done much, much more often, then `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements. And also `SELECT` statement performance will be in highest priority in terms of performance for your application.

Comment: Superb, detailed answer. Thank you very much. The middle-ground solution that Joel proposes seems to resolve all these issues in one go.

Comment: Well, I did notice it - but in fact, that causes duplicate of stored data (which should be always avoided in my opinion. In your case it's only `CHAR` - but in common case compound keys - let's say on set of `VARCHAR`-s cause big overhead). If this isn't a problem for you - then it's ok. But in common case I strongly recommend to use surrogate key and enforce integrity via it

Comment: Actually, it won't be a `CHAR`. It'll be a string of, say, 20 characters. There will be, say, 20 categories and 6 or 7 subcategories. Rate of insert will be relatively low. I'm not convinced by the data-duplication argument: one table holds data, and the other holds a schema of sorts, just like a table with a basic `ENUM` holds possible values and then the actual rows "duplicate" those values in their data. I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: Again - if having duplicated data (one record in main and one in child table) isn't a problem for you - then it's ok to use proposed solution (I've noticed it while typing that long text and didn't include this option so not to "steal" it from the guy who was faster) :p

Answer (score 0):

I'd liked this problem but, with this information I would define a set of valid pairs for just one enum column:

```
CategorySubcategory ENUM("ax", "ay", "az", "bx", "by", "bz", "cx", "cy")
```

I think this will only be useful with a limited set of values, when they got bigger personally I would choose your second option rather than the triggered one.
First reason is absolutely an opinion, I don't like triggers too much, and they don't like me
Second reason is that a well indexed and properly sized reference from one table to another has a really high performance

Comment: IMO this goes the wrong way by merging the categories and subcategories into single values. For single characters, okay, not so bad, but in general...